# ERROR: Failed to parse POMs - Linux

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm getting error which trying to run a job on a new master which I am setting up. The JDK and Maven as configured in Jenkins configuration are present on the Linux server.
(Other jobs which are groovy based have run without issue)
Jenkins: 1.636
Java: 1.8
OS: RHEL 7
Jenkins startup using jenkins.war

Error Stacktrace:

```
Parsing POMs
maven31-agent.jar already up to date
maven31-interceptor.jar already up to date
maven3-interceptor-commons.jar already up to date
[feature-123] $ java -cp /apps/user123/jenkins/jenkins-slave/maven31-agent.jar:/aim/gfs/quad/3rd/apache-maven/3.2.1/common/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:/aim/gfs/quad/3rd/apache-maven/3.2.1/common/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main /aim/gfs/quad/3rd/apache-maven/3.2.1/common /apps/user123/jenkins/jenkins-slave/slave.jar /apps/user123/jenkins/jenkins-slave/maven31-interceptor.jar /apps/user123/jenkins/jenkins-slave/maven3-interceptor-commons.jar 33293
No JDK named ‘null’ found
[feature-123] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2658511214746764047.sh
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/apps/user123/jenkins/jenkins-slave/workspace/feature-123"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
```

Comment: No JDK named ‘null’ found -- I don't think it can find your JDK

Comment: I have the existing master which also shows 'No JDK named ‘null’ found'.
So, that does not indicate the cause of failure.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/apps/user123/jenkins/jenkins-slave/workspace/feature-123"): error=2, **No such file or directory**

Comment: @SiKing yes, the build works if i update the job configuration for the job. I updated the JDK setting from the existing 'system' to 'JDK1.8.0'. However, the existing master works with no such change required.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got to know the root cause. The path variable was not initialized during the slave startup. The master path setting are not picked up by the slaves. So, during the slave startup the PATH must be initialized.
It was as simple as that. All along I was focusing on the master configurations and setting and not paying attention to the Slave startup.

This snippet resolves this issue:

```
PATH="/java_home/bin:$PATH"
nohup java -jar /path_to_slave/slave.jar ........
```